# How do i make my discord.py bot go through a text file and if a user says a word in that file it will delete that message + how to make uptime command

Tags: discord, discord.py

I want my discord.py bot to go through a text file and if a user says a word in that file it will delete that message

```
    elif msg.content == '***':
    await msg.channel.send("Dont curse")
    await msg.delete()
```

that is my code but i want to replace *** with a text document

And also another question i have some issues with an uptime command

```
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is running")
    activity = discord.Game(name="!test", type=3)
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity=activity)
    channel = client.get_channel(944665750453497886)
    myid = '<@516236429689618467>'
    await channel.send("I am online "+myid)
    #Uptime code starts
    global startdate
    startdate = datetime.now()

@client.command()
async def uptime(ctx):
    now = datetime.now()
    uptime = startdate - now
    uptime = uptime.strftime('%d/%h/%M')
    await ctx.send(f'Uptime: {uptime}')
```

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time. Your question literally says what you have to do. Create a text file and go with a `for`-loop over the entries (`for word in xxx` -> `if message.content in xxx` etc.). Even though this should not be a question right now: Where is the problem in your `uptime` command? Please always include a traceback or error.

Comment: the error is  ` Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\rehan\PycharmProjects\discord\main.py", line 19, in <module>
    @client.command()
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'command'`

Comment: I assume you are using `client = discord.Client()`? You have to use `commands.Bot()` to be able to use commands.